# REGEX Remove from end of string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
x = r"""<FNT size='9'>" & [FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER] & "</FNT>"""
```

Trying dynamically using regular expressions or similar to get final result of :

```
[FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER]
```

Cannot hardcore the end result.

I have this to remove the from of string up to first [

```
b = re.sub(r'^.*?\&\s', '', x)
```

But I can't figure out how to do the reverse to the first ] reading from right to left.

I think i need to use the $ sign but I can't get it to work, thanks

Comment: `x = '[FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER]'`?

Comment: what about `\s\&[^&]*$`

Comment: For the people upvoteing @timgeb I don't understand? It needs to be dynamic, I can't just hardcore the end result in

Comment: @TristanForward so why did you not mention that? You explicitly said that you want a string `'[FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER]'`. If you want anything else, you need to specify what characters the brackets can contain.

Comment: @timgeb Apologies, I thought mentioning using regular expressions to do this was clear will edit it

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but `\[.*\]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want the first `[` to the last `]`, you don't even need a regular expression, just `index` and `lastindex`.

```
x = r"""<FNT size='9'>" & [FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER] & "</FNT>"""

open = x.find("[")
close = x.rfind("]")

print(x[open:close + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the first open square `bracket` and then get all characters to the next closing square `bracket` and then all characters to the final closing square `bracket`:

```
x = r"""<FNT size='9'>" & [FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER] & "</FNT>"""

x = re.findall("\[.*?\].*?\]", x)[0]
```

which modifies `x` to:

```
'[FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
\[.+\]
# match [, anything else, backtrack to the first ] found
```

Instead of *removing everything*, you could simply *extract the desired output*.

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = """
<FNT size='9'>" & [FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER] & "</FNT>
<FNT size='9'>" & [anything else] & " " & [something here] & "</FNT>
"""

rx = re.compile(r'\[.+\]')

matches = [match.group(0) for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print(matches)
# ['[FacilityID] & " " & [DIAMETER]', '[anything else] & " " & [something here]']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/S9nZUU/2).